# How to speed up eslint on project with tons of files?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have a git repo with probably 20GB of content (it's a git LFS large file storage project for saving data), mostly JSON/CSV/YAML files, with random `.ts` and `.js` TypeScript/JavaScript files scattered around these "data" files. It seems as the repo has grown, I now get this basically every time I try and save a `.ts` or `.js` file:

[image]

It waits like that (the pink bar at the bottom moving from left to right a bunch), for probably 3+ minutes every time I press CMD+s to save on my Mac. I have basic ESLint and prettier configured.

`.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": ["./tsconfig.json"]
  },
  "ignorePatterns": ["**/*.js", "import/github/**/*/data"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
    "simple-import-sort",
    "typescript-sort-keys",
    "sort-keys",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "extends": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "curly": 2,
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
      "error",
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true,
        "allowTemplateLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/array-type": [
      2,
      {
        "default": "generic"
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/await-thenable": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions": [2, "type"],
    "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-exports": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/method-signature-style": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/naming-convention": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-for-in-array": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-this-alias": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-useless-empty-export": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-function-type": "off",
    "no-array-constructor": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-array-constructor": "off",
    "no-throw-literal": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-throw-literal": "off",
    "lines-between-class-members": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/lines-between-class-members": "off",
    "object-curly-spacing": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/object-curly-spacing": [2, "always"],
    "padding-line-between-statements": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/padding-line-between-statements": [
      "error",
      {
        "blankLine": "always",
        "prev": "*",
        "next": ["type"]
      }
    ],
    "space-before-blocks": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/space-before-blocks": ["error", "always"],
    "@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing": [
      "error",
      { "after": true }
    ],
    "import/first": "error",
    "import/newline-after-import": "error",
    "import/no-duplicates": "error",
    "typescript-sort-keys/interface": "off",
    "typescript-sort-keys/string-enum": "off",
    "sort-keys": 0,
    "sort-keys/sort-keys-fix": "off",
    "prettier/prettier": 2,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
    "default-case": "off",
    "default-case-last": "off"
  }
}
```

`.prettierrc.json`:

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 72,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "proseWrap": "always",
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "singleAttributePerLine": true,
  "prettierPath": "./node_modules/prettier",
  "importOrder": ["^\\w(.*)$", "^@(.*)$", "~(.*)$", "\\..(.*)$", "\\.(.*)$"],
  "importOrderSeparation": true,
  "importOrderSortSpecifiers": true
}
```

`.tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "outDir": "host",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "strict": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "types": ["node"],
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "declaration": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "files": true
  },
  "include": ["*.ts", "**/*.ts", "*.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "host"]
}
```

I've restarted my computer and quit VSCode several times, but still getting this issue. Like I said, it only seems to happen when repositories become large, so I'm not sure what the culprit is, or if it can be fixed. Any ideas what can be done?

Basically, the file won't save until 3+ minutes of "processing" for some reason, which is quite annoying.

Comment: Configure ESLint to stop linting the large files? So put the large file in certain folders and add those folders to the `ignorePatterns` of eslintrc and `exclude` of tsconfig. Basically, be sure you're linting what you want linted. If you are already doing that then I'd turn off ESLint on save and only run it before you push it to your repo or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS code has the option to activate ESlint only on specific file extensions, see here: [How can I make eslint/vscode-eslint stop linting .eslintrc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153736/how-can-i-make-eslint-vscode-eslint-stop-linting-eslintrc)

Also you can try using .eslintignore files: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/ignore